# How to decode utf-8 encoded string in python 3?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following situation:

```
encoded_string = str('дис'.encode('utf-8'))
```

I need to convert this to string because django's `set_cookie()` takes a string and I can't seem to be able to write the function `decode_string` for which:

```
decode_string(encoded_string) == 'дис'
```

is again. If I don't convert this string then django returns Internal server error.
Can you please help?

UPDATE:

I wish I could avoid the `str()` step, but that is not up to me. Django's set_cookie converts bytestrings to str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm it seems that if I use `'дис'.encode('unicode-escape')`  then

```
def decode_string(encoded_string: str) -> str:
    return bytes(encoded_string.replace('\\\\','\\')[2:-1], 'utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

is a solution, but it looks messy to me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `str()`, use `decode`.

```
>>> 'дис' == 'дис'.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
True
```

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: You should put your actual Django code in the question. If you're dealing with an encoded string, you just pass the decoded value to `set_cookie()`, e.g. `set_cookie("my_cookie", encoded_string.decode('utf-8'))`.